# Deep cloning Entity instances in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Attempting this:

```
/**
 * Deep clones an array of instances of type T and returns a new array.
 * @param array The array to deep clone
 * @return A new deep clone of the array argument
 *
 * @example
<pre>
  const original = [new Todo(), new Todo()];
  const result = [new Todo(), new Todo()];
  expect(deepClone(original)).to.eql(result);
</pre>
*/
export function deepClone<T extends Object>(array: T[]): T[] {
  return array.map((e:T) => ({...e}));
}
```

Typescript says:

> [ts] Spread types may only be created from object types.

Should not `T extends Object` take care of this?

Comment: This is just not supported: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26412

Comment: You have to use a type assertion unfortunately. `array.map((e:T) => (<object>{...e}));` it's ugly but it works if you know what you are doing. FYI, you are using the wrong type in your constraint. It should be `object`

Comment: I tried it but now it says `Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's getting warmer, but now it says: `[ts] Type 'object' cannot be converted to type 'T'.`

Comment: So add `<unknown>` in between: `array.map((e) => <T>(<unknown><object>{...e}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you duplicate an object with the spread operator, your new object won't be an instance of a class, but a literal object with no type, so it won't be a real clone of the existing object.

If the objects you want to clone are defined by you (not an external library) you could do something like:

```
export function deepClone(array: any[]): any[] {
  return array.map((e:any) => (new e.constructor(e)));
}
```

And then in your classes meant to be cloned:

```
constructor(obj: any) {
   Object.assign(this, obj);
}
```

Comment: This only works if the top level properties are value types like strings and numbers. Reference objects are the same instance of the object and not a deep clone.

Comment: @AdrianBrand you're right, this can be solved by defining a setter on every property that has a non-primitive type

Comment: I am questioning the validity of the explanation. This feels like a limitation of the compiler, not a problem with the approach as stated in the answer. The only question is: does a result satisfy interface T or no? There is no such thing as "instance of a class" in JavaScript nor TypeScript.

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović as stated in the comments it's a limitation of Typescript. My answer states that the `{...e}` approach does not create a similar object, because even if you don't want to call it "instance of a class", there **are** types in Javascript, and many related keywords (`instanceof`, `typeof`, `new`, `constructor`, etc...). And the spread operator does not reflect the type of the source object.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qmzgf7

```
const clone = obj =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
      ? new Date(obj.getTime())
      : (typeof obj === 'object') && obj
        ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => ({ ...o, [prop]: clone(obj[prop]) }), {})
        : obj;
```

It doesn't work for all JavaScript object you might encounter, but it will likely work for anything that comes from a server call in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your actual implementation, you should consider using old mate JSON to help you out with this.

```js
var array:Array<number> = [1,2,3];
var deepClone = clone(array);
deepClone[0] = 99;
console.log({ array, deepClone });  // returns [1,2,3] & [99,2,3]

function clone<T>(array:T[]) {
return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)) as Array<T>;
}
```